# Android: Title Bar Color don't change

Tags: android, layout, colors, mono, titlebar

I wanna change my Apps Titlebar color and tried it in this way:

Part of the manifest file:

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"  
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTitleBar" ></application>
```

The style block part of the file styles.xml:

```
 <style name="Theme.MyTitleBar" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:colorBackground">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
 </style>
```

But only the text color and attributes changes correct. Any guest what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I added the part for the ActionBar (sorry I put only for Dialogs at first)

You can follow this, it will allow you to change moreover other attributes that just the title bar:

Just call your custom theme in the manifest file:

```
 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"  
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Then create these 2 styles in your `styles.xml`. The first one defines the theme, the second one, one of the styles to apply on the theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">     
    <item name="android:colorBackground">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>
```

**NOTE:** In this example, I customize the theme Holo Light as you can see with this: `android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar`.

Comment: thanks for your fast answer, but it will not helpful.

1st I wanna change the Title not the Action Bar

but 2nd:
Why I have to declare the theme and add an other theme? That seem strange. Why I can't set all attributes in one step?

Comment: I tried the code and the background became white as expected, have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I have, on a HTC One. 
I will try the emulator

Comment: I tried it on the software emulator. The Background is light grey (emulator background color) the Attributes of the text are set correct. 

hm this is crazy

Answer (score 0):

Add This style.xml File in your project according to your requirment...

```
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/myActionBar</item>

</style>



<style name="myActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">    
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/myActionBar.titleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="myActionBar.titleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/darkgrey</item>
</style>

 <style name="myActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">#e6ebc3</item>
</style>
```