# actionBar change MenuItem title color and default icon group

Tags: android, android-actionbar

i have this menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app_name="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:id="@+id/menu_title"
    android:title="@string/details_title"
    app_name:showAsAction="always" />

<group android:id="@+id/options"
    app_name:showAsAction="ifRoom">

    <item android:id="@+id/option1"
          android:title="@string/title1" />
    <item android:id="@+id/option2"
          android:title="@string/title2" />
</group>
```

my default style is Theme.AppCompat.Light, but i want to change title color of menu_title. how i can fix it to white? How change default icon of group? thanks!

Comment: i think for changing color you need t use style.

Comment: yes but what style i have to override?

Comment: see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770015/android-title-bar-color-dont-change

Comment: i tried it but title item is always black..

Comment: which color code you are using?